# MSIEXEC return codes 0 is success

Tags: batch-file, psexec, windows-installer

I am trying to figure out how to have this script push out flash writing a txt file showing the ones that passed and failed. For some reason I can not get the txt file to show "98/100 successful" or "100/100 Successful" on the bottom or the top of the txt file it creates so that I do not have to search the entire file to make sure it shows `with error code 0.` to know it passed. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set active_success=0
set plugin_success=0
set total=0

for /F %%G IN (test.txt) DO ( 
    set /a total+=1
    psexec \\%%G -e -h -u tc\alert -p Pw#1 -n 5 msiexec /i "\\Install\Adobe\Flash\flash_player_active_x.msi" /qn >> DE_Flash.txt 2>&1
    IF !ERRORLEVEL!==0 set /a active_success+=1
    psexec \\%%G -e -h -u tc\alert -p Pw#1 -n 5 msiexec /i "\\Install\Adobe\Flash\flash_player_plugin.msi" /qn >> DE_Flash.txt 2>&1
    IF !ERRORLEVEL!==0 set /a plugin_success+=1
)
```

Comment: You really need to stop DELETING you QUESTIONS.  It is extremely rude when I am trying to help you!!!!

Comment: In your previous question I stated, **echo the variables as needed**.  That means ECHO the variables at the end of the batch file.  Either redirect them to your DE_Flash.txt file or just echo them to the screen.

Comment: You are already using redirection in your original code!  How can you not know how to redirect them!